# why my css file doesn't reload?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have an aspx page with two css links:

```
 <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=MyPath %>/Profile.css" id="Link1" runat="server" visible="false" />
<link href="../../Style/ProfileMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" visible="true" />
```

Each take care of different elements and no dupliacate class names.
when I run the code it works perfect, when i click **submit** the page reloads but the second css doesnt work.

I tried adding to the first css all the info from the second css and delete the second css (use only one css per page) and nothing changed.
I guess there is a problem with postback..

why ? how to fix it ? how can i check it?

Comment: when you click submit the page changes ?

Comment: yes all the style properties from the second css disappear

Comment: Does it not load or does it not get applied? Is the fetching of the second sheet failing (check the browser network log)? Or is it not even trying? Is the second page cached in the browser and not including the new sheet link?

Comment: Your first sheet uses `"<%=MyPath %>/Profile.css"` to link to it while the second uses `"../../Style/ProfileMenu.css"`, which is a relative path. If you've moved the sheet or the page in the directory structure, then "../../" might no longer be valid (returning a 404 response).  Try changing the second to `"<%=MyPath %>/Style/ProfileMenu.css"`.

Comment: on the first load the both are load, after submit the second css seem to be loaded but no changes on aspx page.

Comment: @ Anthony tried it and after the path change the second css doesnt loaded at all.

Comment: well i checked it again and in both-the load and the submit the :
Profile.css returning 404.
ProfileMenu.css returning OK.
I am confused the css returning OK is the problematic one...why?

Comment: Can you make the paths absolute? I suspect you could use `<link href="/Style/ProfileMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />` for the second one, and do something similar for the `MyPath` variable. Also, `visible` is not a standard attribute for a [`<link>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).